# Problema con los Index Primary Key identity dan saltos enormes en tablas.

Tags: sql, sql-server

En algunas ocasiones la base de datos me han dado salto digamos que de de ir en 200,000 hasta 250,000 o incluso mayores. 
Alguna idea de como pueda hacer una búsqueda en log, para determinar el problema, algunas recomendación de posible causas o información que me sirva mas al respecto. ?

Comment: Por qué sería esto un problema?

Comment: Algunos sistemas usan el identity como un contador para saber cantidades totales. Se tiene como previsto un cambio en la logica de las aplicaciones para evitar esos problemas. Pero ahorita me gustaria saber como algunas recomendaciones para evitar esto, saber como se puede monitorear o determinar mas a fondo la causa.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A primera vista, diría que no utilices identity si requieres una garantía de que tus llaves primarias no tengan "agujeros"; es decir, que falten números dentro de la secuencia, pero pensándolo mejor, diría que no veo una razón para imponer una restricción tal como esa a un sistema de la vida real.

Te explico lo de los agujeros.

Voy a suponer que hablamos de un sistema que

1. Utiliza transacciones explícitas (aunque también podrían ser implícitas en el caso de un Stored Procedure o un Trigger).
2. Podría o no tener acceso concurrente.

### Rollback, el principal culpable.

En resumen, es fácil conseguir agujeros en la llave primaria teniendo simplemente transacciones que terminan con un `rollback` y no `commit`. Creo que un ejemplo vale más que mil palabras.

```
create table TestIdentity (
  IDColumn int identity(1, 1) primary key
, Numero int
);

commit;
go

begin transaction

insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (1);
insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (1);
insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (1);
insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (1);

commit;
go

begin transaction

insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (2);
insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (2);
insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (2);
insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (2);

rollback;
go

begin transaction

insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (3);
insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (3);
insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (3);
insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (3);

commit;
go

select *
  from TestIdentity;
go
```

El resultado del último select es:

```
IDColumn    Numero
----------- -----------
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
9           3
10          3
11          3
12          3
```

Como puedes observar, súbitamente *faltan* 4 números en nuestra llave primaria. Estos se perdieron en la transacción que hizo rollback.

Otra pequeña prueba con concurrencia, es decir, varios usuarios que insertan registros simultáneamente, requiere que utilices dos conexiones distintas (por ejemplo, dos pestañas en el *SQL Server Management Studio*,

Primero ejecuto en ambas conexiones la sentencia `begin transaction`, luego alternadamente la sentencia `insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (5);` en la primera pestaña y la sentencia `insert into TestIdentity (Numero) values (6);` en la segunda pestaña.

Lo ejecuto, digamos 3 veces en la primera, 3 veces en la segunda, pero uno a uno, es decir, voy a la primera, ejecuto, luego a la segunda, ejecuto, regreso a la primera, ejecuto, y así.

Luego en la primera ejecuto la sentencia `commit` y en la segunda la sentencia `rollback`. Un nuevo `select` sobre la tabla me arroja ahora:

```
IDColumn    Numero
----------- -----------
1           1
2           1
3           1
4           1
9           3
10          3
11          3
12          3
13          4
15          4
17          4
```

Si observas, solamente quedaron los registros con *número* 4, pero la llave primaria va dando saltos, donde va quedando un número entre cada valor.

### Los valores no utilizados en caché se pierden al reiniciar el servidor

SQL Server 2012, por ejemplo, utiliza un caché de 1,000 para los valores `IDENTITY` en columnas de tipo `int`. Al reiniciar el servicio, los valores no utilizados en caché se pierden. (El tamaño del caché es de 10,000 para `bigint`/`numeric`).

La [Documentación](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/esn-gt/library/ms186775.aspx) dice:

> **Valores consecutivos después de un reinicio del servidor u otros errores**: SQL Server podría almacenar en memoria caché los valores de identidad por motivos de rendimiento y algunos de los valores asignados podrían perderse durante un error de la base de datos o un reinicio del servidor. Esto puede tener como resultado espacios en el valor de identidad al insertarlo. Si no es aceptable que haya espacios, la aplicación debe usar mecanismos propios para generar valores de clave. El uso de un generador de secuencias con la opción NOCACHE puede limitar los espacios a transacciones que nunca se llevan a cabo.

Es probable que haya otros escenarios dónde se generen más agujeros, ahora no me vienen a la mente, pero los más comunes son estos dos.

Encontrar un salto de 50,000 registros no es más que evidencia que

- Los registros existieron y fueron eliminados, o
- hubo una o varias transacciones que en total insertaron esa cantidad de registros, pero que terminaron con `rollback`
- hubo una combinación de los anteriores con reinicios del servidor.